# Get Unique Values from a list of Objects

Tags: list, object, salesforce, apex-code, distinct-values

`Public Class Related Practice{ String Name; Integer id; }`

Given a list of 'Related Practice' Objects, I want to extract unique 'Name' values(Distinct values) from the List .

I made an attempt, but it doesn't work for all cases, if anyone has any better ideas ?

```
//This method return unique values from a list
    private static List<Related_Practice__c> getUniqueValues(List<Related_Practice__c> listInput){
        List<Related_Practice__c> listOutput = new List<Related_Practice__c>();
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i<listInput.size();i++){
            for(Integer j = 0;j<listInput.size();j++){
                if(i != j){
                   if(listInput[j].Practice_Name__c == listInput[i].Practice_Name__c){
                    
                    listInput.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        listOutput.addAll(listInput);
        return listOutput;
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Map` instead of using `List`

```
//This method return unique values from a list
    private static List<Related_Practice__c> getUniqueValues(List<Related_Practice__c> listInput){
        
        Map<String,Related_Practice__c> listOutputMap = new Map<String,Related_Practice__c>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i<listInput.size();i++){
            if(!listOutputMap.containsKey(listInput[i].Practice_Name__c)){
                listOutputMap.put(listInput[i].Practice_Name__c,listInput[i])
            }
           
        }
        
        return listOutputMap.values();
    }
```